# Normally it's said, Company "A" uses MySQL for DBs. Does it mean MySQL free edition or MySQL Enterprise edition?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database

I am almost close to settling with MySQL over PostgreSQL (over the reasons I wrote on my [blog here](http://iscans.blogspot.com/2011/11/mysql-vs-postgresql-rdbmss.html)).

Too small things bother me here:

- It's often said that MySQL is the most used RDBMS, among those that are available for free (alongside PostgreSQL, Firebird etc). And in order to support their stance on MySQL, many refer to Facebook, Twitter, Flickr, Wikipedia, YouTube etc using MySQL. One thing is not clear. Are they referring to the freely downloadable MySQL or the paid enterprise version (known as "Oracle MySQL")?
- According to Wikipedia, under pressure from open source software advocates, `"As part of the negotiations with the European Commission, Oracle committed that MySQL server will continue to use the dual-licensing strategy long used by MySQL AB with commercial and GPL versions available **until at least 2015**."` No one seems to be worried as to what happens after that?

Comment: http://mariadb.org/ http://www.drizzle.org/

Comment: I asked 2 questions, and I got two answers (below) answering a question each. hmm... =)

Comment: I think mySQL licensing issues only come into play when you distribute your app - If you're just a website, there's no cost involved.  Also, your comparison might be out of date.  PG has built in streaming replication in 9.x, and has supported it with third party add-ons for years.

Comment: ok, I can copy them and assemble in one answer, so you can accept mine :-) just kidding

Comment: Mike Christensen : Thanks corrected. The huge disappoint with PostgreSQL is that large-scale deployment hosting service providers (like Softlayer) do not manage PostgreSQL. They out right told me that they only offer support for MySQL (among the free DBMSs). - - @stivlo : hehe!

Comment: Yea I wish more hosts would support PG, I think it's a better DB all around.  Here's a list of hosting companies in North America that run PG: http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_hosting_northamerica

Comment: @Mike Christensen My choices are kinda limited - - among the league are Rackspace, Softlayer, Voxel, Peer 1 etc - - as I am looking for large-scale managed hosting service providers who can provide petabytes to exabytes of storage and transfer (mine is a photo sharing app).

Comment: I use Rackspace for my site, and I run Postgres9.  Never had any problems.  Their customer support is fantastic.

Comment: @Mike Christensen Yeah, they're on my list. Thanks for the suggestion. And hey, a softlayer rep. told me that they're planning to offer PG in 5-8 months time frame. Always happy to have a choice! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the advantages of the paid version are mostly support and accountability. Most (especially large) companies like to be able to point fingers to someone when things blow up.

Comment: Yea, though you can pretty much find paid support for any database out there.  For example, EnterpriseDB offers PG support along with their enterprise distribution: http://www.enterprisedb.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are afraid of Oracle's handling of MySQL, just use [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org/).  MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL that is open source which appears to have been forked because of fears about Oracle's (potential) handling of MySQL.